# Mount & Blade: Enter Battle Without Horse

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband, mount-and-blade-viking-conquest

In Mount and Blade (Specifically Warband and Viking Conquest), if you have a horse equipped on you then on the map screen, you are able to move much faster. A great advantage, however though, in battle you start on the horse aswell. This is all fine when fighting with calvary, but when fighting with infantry and archers (especially in VC), being mounted can be awkward. I would like to be able to fight by my men without having to dismount, meaning I fall behind like a cowardly leader. 

 
*Is there some way (I'm open for a simple mod) that allows you to have a horse equipped in the map screen, but start dismounted in battles?*

Comment: Why don't you use commands to tell them to wait while you dismount, then tell them to charge or follow you into battle when you're ready?

Comment: If it is an advantage for you to dismount, you should tell everyone else to do so too...

Comment: In VC especially, all my troops do not have mounts. The problem is my men get ahead while I am dismounting. I am not talking about when I have an all cavalry army.
@Paul that may be a good idea. Aside from having to load the command screen each battle, it will solve the problem.

Comment: @PlanetAlexander Command screen? I would definitely use the keyboard shortcuts if you're not. Hit 0 (select Everyone), F2 (Follow me) or F1 (hold this position), F4 (Dismount), dismount yourself, then F3 (charge) or have them continue following you into battle.